# powershell: How to pass environment variable in RUN command

Tags: powershell, dockerfile, environment-variables

I am trying to find a solution to the following simple problem. I would like to run the following cmake command:

```
> cmake "-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:PKG_VERSION" ..
```

It appears to be the correct syntax for this task (per [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-5.1)).

The trouble is that this syntax does not work from within my [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

Here are my failed attempt and the result I see:

```
[...]
Step 20/34 : RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION="$($Env:PKG_VERSION)
 ---> Running in b02cebc8e124
-DPKG_VERSION=$
0.6.9
 ---> Removed intermediate container b02cebc8e124
 ---> 479fe1a125e8
Step 21/34 : RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION="$Env:PKG_VERSION
 ---> Running in 8fc29b675b90
-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:
PKG_VERSION
 ---> Removed intermediate container 8fc29b675b90
 ---> 66372d417c9f
Step 22/34 : RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION="${Env:PKG_VERSION}
 ---> Running in a014a9490f0a
-DPKG_VERSION=$
Env:PKG_VERSION
 ---> Removed intermediate container a014a9490f0a
 ---> 35befba98602
Step 23/34 : RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION=$($Env:PKG_VERSION)"
 ---> Running in 03d126ef5aa5
-DPKG_VERSION=$
0.6.9
 ---> Removed intermediate container 03d126ef5aa5
 ---> 464ca62cf985
Step 24/34 : RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:PKG_VERSION"
 ---> Running in 34c83b2b01df
-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:
PKG_VERSION
 ---> Removed intermediate container 34c83b2b01df
 ---> 632bc7a489da
Step 25/34 : RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION=${Env:PKG_VERSION}"
 ---> Running in da1640fbd40f
-DPKG_VERSION=$
Env:PKG_VERSION
 ---> Removed intermediate container da1640fbd40f
 ---> 341a14ec1552
Step 26/34 : RUN echo '-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:PKG_VERSION'
 ---> Running in f4038c2feb51
-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:PKG_VERSION
 ---> Removed intermediate container f4038c2feb51
 ---> e209c03cb636
Step 27/34 : RUN echo '-DPKG_VERSION=$($Env:PKG_VERSION)'
 ---> Running in c57df5ce803c
-DPKG_VERSION=$($Env:PKG_VERSION)
```

Question: what is the right way for passing environment variable in powershell (inside a `Dockerfile`) ?

---

Update: Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
> docker build envvar
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/8 : ARG WSCI_VERSION=ltsc2019
Step 2/8 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:${WSCI_VERSION}
 ---> c632661e39bb
Step 3/8 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6b5e34b83047
Step 4/8 : ENV PKG_VERSION=1.2.3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6419bdf10920
Step 5/8 : RUN $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
 ---> Running in 02cdd6ef5360

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  5122


Removing intermediate container 02cdd6ef5360
 ---> 97b514422293
Step 6/8 : RUN echo PKG_VERSION=${Env:PKG_VERSION}
 ---> Running in cb0de097efd9
PKG_VERSION=1.2.3
Removing intermediate container cb0de097efd9
 ---> ff8bc0534c61
Step 7/8 : RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:PKG_VERSION"
 ---> Running in 392ffea7a55b
-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:
PKG_VERSION
Removing intermediate container 392ffea7a55b
 ---> b66d9765535a
Step 8/8 : RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION=${Env:PKG_VERSION}"
 ---> Running in 2f8f4d33983f
-DPKG_VERSION=$
Env:PKG_VERSION
Removing intermediate container 2f8f4d33983f
 ---> 6f22a75f80e8
Successfully built 6f22a75f80e8
```

with

```
> cat .\envvar\Dockerfile
# escape=`
ARG WSCI_VERSION=ltsc2019
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:${WSCI_VERSION}

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ENV PKG_VERSION=1.2.3

RUN $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
RUN echo PKG_VERSION=${Env:PKG_VERSION}
RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:PKG_VERSION"
RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION=${Env:PKG_VERSION}"
```

Comment: Try escaping `$`: `RUN echo "-DPKG_VERSION=$$Env:PKG_VERSION"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *Windows*, Docker doesn't automatically perform the `\`-escaping of `"` characters that [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, requires in code passed to its `-Command` (`-c`) parameter.

- Note: The **problem does *not* arise on *Unix*-like platforms**, where there's no process-level command line and arguments are passed as an array of verbatim tokens.

Therefore, **on Windows**, be sure to **manually `\`-escape `"` chars.** that are part  of your command:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
RUN echo \"-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:PKG_VERSION\"
RUN echo \"-DPKG_VERSION=${Env:PKG_VERSION}\"
```

---

As an aside:

- The curious symptoms that resulted *without* `"` escaping stem from a known parameter-binder bug in PowerShell, where an - in effect - *unquoted* argument such as `-DPKG_VERSION=$Env:PKG_VERSION` is unexpectedly split into *two* arguments at the first `:` - see [GitHub issue #6360](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6360).
- A simple way to reproduce this on Windows is to run the following from `cmd.exe`:

  ```bash
  :: Run from cmd.exe
  powershell.exe -Command echo "-FOO=$ENV:OS"
  ```

  - PowerShell's initial CLI command-line parsing *removes* the the `"` instances because they're *unescaped* (see below for background information), so that what ultimately executes is `echo -FOO=$Env:OS`, which triggers the bug and emits *two* strings, verbatim `-FOO=$Env:` and verbatim `OS`.

---

###### Background information on `\` vs. `` ` ``-escaping in PowerShell:

Given that *inside* a PowerShell session it is `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*, that serves as the [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters), it may be surprising that ***on the CLI command line* `\` must be used to escape `"` chars in `-Command` arguments**.<sup>[1]</sup>

Presumably, this was done to align with most other CLIs, which either require or also support this kind of `"`-escaping and to be able to use standard techniques for command-line parsing. Note that
**escaping `"` as `\"` is an *additional, preliminary layer of escaping* solely for the PowerShell CLI's *command-line parsing***:

- *Unescaped* `"` are assumed to simply protect arguments from the calling shell and are *removed* during command-line parsing.
- *Escaped* `"` (`\"`) are assumed to be *part of the PowerShell code* to execute via `-Command` in then-*unescaped* form - where they may or may not have *syntactic* function.
  (In `-File` invocations, `\"` is  assumed to be a *verbatim* `"` char. inside a pass-through argument).

In short: *unescaped* `"` are removed, escaped `"` are preserved *as `"`*, and the result - possibly stitched together with spaces from what were technically multiple arguments on the command line - is *then* interpreted *as PowerShell code*, where the usual syntax and escaping rules apply.

Notably, this means that **`` ` ``-escaping may *additionally* be needed** to satisfy PowerShell's syntax rules:

- If an (originally escaped) `"` appears inside an (originally escaped) `"..."` string; e.g., from `cmd.exe`:

```bash
:: From cmd.exe - note the `\" sequences.
:: Prints: 'Nat "King" Cole'
powershell.exe -Command "echo \"Nat `\"King`\" Cole\""``</sup>
```

- In *shell-free* invocations,<sup>[2]</sup> such as from automation tools (including when building a Dockerfile) and scheduled tasks, where passing *multiline* arguments to the PowerShell CLI is possible (without needing to also satisfy the line-continuation syntax of a calling shell), `` ` `` is situationally still needed for *line-continuations*, as shown [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77947524/45375):

```bash
# Part of your Dockerfile on Windows, assuming # escape=` is in effect.
# Note that *both* \-escaping (\")
# *and* `-escaping (line-continuations) are needed:
RUN echo "-Dfirst" `
         \"-DPKG_VERSION=${Env:PKG_VERSION}\" `
         "-Dthird"
```

Note that a [**`` # escape=` ``**  parser directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#escape) in a Dockerfile allows Docker to recognize PowerShell's line continuations as such, so that their use to spread `RUN` instructions across multiple lines doesn't run afoul of *Docker's* parsing.

The directive does *not* otherwise affect the content passed to the target shell, *except* that Docker actually *removes* the line continuations behind the scenes and passes a *single-line* representation to the shell.

It is therefore technically possible - though perhaps confusing - to *not* use this directive - and use `\` for line-continuation (even though PowerShell wouldn't understand it, it never gets to see it).

---

<sup>[1] [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI, alternatively also (robustly) accepts `""` in lieu of `\"`. `""` can help avoid running afoul of `cmd.exe`'s command-line parsing, but in *shell-free* invocations of the PowerShell CLI - such as performed during a Docker build behind the scenes - `\"` works robustly.

In PowerShell CLI invocations with the `-File` parameter (invoking a `.ps1` *script file*), no interpretation of the arguments *as PowerShell code* occurs, and `\"` is only needed to *embed verbatim `"` chars.* in pass-through arguments.</sup>

<sup>[2] By that I mean that the PowerShell CLI is invoked *directly* (ultimately via a WinAPI call), not from *another shell*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to @mklement0's answer, here is the full `Dockerfile`. Pay attention that Dockerfile `escape character` is set to (`` ` ``), but the quotes (`"`) are escaped with a backslash (`\`).

```
> cat .\envvar\Dockerfile
# escape=`
ARG WSCI_VERSION=ltsc2019
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:${WSCI_VERSION}

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ENV PKG_VERSION=1.2.3

RUN $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
RUN echo "-Dfirst" `
         \"-DPKG_VERSION=${Env:PKG_VERSION}\" `
         "-Dthird"
```

Gives:

```
> docker build --no-cache envvar
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/6 : ARG WSCI_VERSION=ltsc2019
Step 2/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:${WSCI_VERSION}
 ---> c632661e39bb
Step 3/6 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Running in 1f755597e78a
Removing intermediate container 1f755597e78a
 ---> 719550de3ad0
Step 4/6 : ENV PKG_VERSION=1.2.3
 ---> Running in 4d900ad04cd3
Removing intermediate container 4d900ad04cd3
 ---> 55f195f7562b
Step 5/6 : RUN $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
 ---> Running in c07fd6390b64

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  5122


Removing intermediate container c07fd6390b64
 ---> 1c199a9c289c
Step 6/6 : RUN echo "-Dfirst"          \"-DPKG_VERSION=${Env:PKG_VERSION}\"              "-Dthird"
 ---> Running in 295dda66d9fc
-Dfirst
-DPKG_VERSION=1.2.3
-Dthird
Removing intermediate container 295dda66d9fc
 ---> 8689bd2efd88
Successfully built 8689bd2efd88
```

---

Also CMake seems to support a space ( ) character in between `-D` and the variable name. To avoid the quote \-escape, one could also do:

```
RUN cmake "-Dfirst" `
         -D PKG_VERSION=${Env:PKG_VERSION} `
         "-Dthird"
```

Comment: Yes, it may be surprising that _on the CLI command line_ `"` chars. must be escaped with ``\`` rather than the usual PowerShell escape character, `\`` (backtick). I've added an additional section with background information to my answer.