# Installing exe inside Windows container using PowerShell

Tags: .net, docker, powershell, powershell-core, powershell-7.3

I am facing problem with installation of .exe file inside docker container:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS base
SHELL ["pwsh", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN dotnet tool install --global --version 7.3.11 PowerShell 
ADD https://downloads.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-c/4.9.2/netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DAP-64.exe lib/netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DAP-64.exe
RUN start-process -Filepath "C:\lib\netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DAP-64.exe" -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList "/S" , "/D=C:\NetCdf"

CMD ["pwsh"]
```

After `docker build .` all steps are running correctly till installation step... Output shows no file to be process:

```
Step 6/7 : RUN start-process -Filepath "C:\lib\netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DAP-64.exe" -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList "/S" , "/D=C:\NetCdf"
 ---> Running in 8e200fa39c0f

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
      0     0.00       0.00       0.00    1544

Removing intermediate container 8e200fa39c0f
```

Checked manually and by "RUN Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\lib\netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DAP-64.exe" that file is present.

Checked by running...

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2 AS base

ADD https://downloads.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-c/4.9.2/netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DAP-64.exe lib/netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DAP-64.exe
RUN powershell Start-Process -filepath 'C:\lib\netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DAP-64.exe' -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList '/S' , '/D=C:\NetCdf'
```

...that for old normal PowerShell application is installed correctly:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    168      11     1724       8688       0.09   2292   1 netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DA...
```

Executing command manually inside container also worked

---

Is there any related known bug with pwsh tool?
Is there better way to install this file with CMD or even dotnet somehow?
I spent whole day on trying to make it work, so any help would appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to install any .exe file with mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 - this one is too limited. Instead I used aspnet:7.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 and there powershell scripts worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**:

- While the information below is true in general, the solution offered turned out *not* to make a difference, as the command should work even *without* quoting the strings involved.

---

- In principle, you need to `\`-escape `"` characters in `RUN` instructions when using PowerShell (either edition) as the shell in a *Windows* image.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77927378/45375) for background information.
- Unfortunately, however, this isn't enough due to a long-standing bug in the *.NET tool version* of PowerShell (Core), which doesn't honor even properly escaped `"` chars. - see [GitHub issue #11747](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11747)

Therefore, simply use [*single-quoted* (`'...'` aka *verbatim*) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) in your command (as you did in the Windows PowerShell call, to `powershell.exe`):

```bash
RUN Start-Process -Filepath 'C:\lib\netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DAP-64.exe' -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList '/S /D=C:\NetCdf'
```

Note:

- This simple workaround is possible in your case, because your command happens not to require *expansions* (string interpolation)  (which only [*expandable* (`"..."`) string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) in PowerShell provide).
- Since `'` chars. have no syntactic function on the PowerShell CLI's *command line*, they can be used without escaping.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] There's a largely hypothetical caveat: Unless everything that follows `-Command` is `"..."`-enclosed *overall*, the interior of `'...'` strings that contain spaces are technically passed as *multiple* arguments, which are then stitched back together with a *single space* as the separator, before the result is then interpreted as PowerShell code. This results in *whitespace normalization*: that is, runs of *two or more spaces* turn into a *single* space each; e.g., `'foo     bar'` would become `'foo bar'`</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately single quote does not work either

Comment: Good point, @Julia: I now see that your command would work even without any quoting at all, given that the strings do not contain spaces and contain no PowerShell metacharacters.

Comment: @Julia: It's clearly starting _some_ process. Could it be that this simply a _display_ problem, and that the installer ran properly just the same, or have you verified that it doesn't run?

Comment: @Julia: It looks like a version of `pwsh` is _preinstalled_ in the image, otherwise it wouldn't be able to run the `RUN dotnet tool ...` instruction that installs `pwsh` as a global tool, right? Which version is that?

Comment: On second thought: the process-info display output looks suspect overall, not just due to the missing process _name_.

Comment: I checked that netCDF4.9.2-NC4-DAP-64.exe is created in container, but the location for files that should be installed is not even created. It seems like the installation is missing something in container from mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 image, but I can't took out logs from it. I tried "-RedirectStandardOutput stdout.txt -RedirectStandardError stderr.txt" commands, but files turned out to be empty. Also I tried the same scenario with 7zip installer and the result was the same. For mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2 image everything works smooth for both - netcdf and 7zip .exes.

Comment: @Julia, I'm assuming that https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c is the ultimate source of the binaries you're trying to install, right? If so, you may be missing C/C++ runtimes in your image. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist